# Passing wrong data through segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboard

I'm trying to randomize the questions for my quiz and have the segue appear if the answer was answered incorrectly. I think it may have to do with my NewNumber() but I cannot figure it out.

Sometimes it works for the first 3 questions but then even when the correct answer is selected through the button the segue is triggered.

So, what I'd love is:
-randomized questions (no repeats, but I had to get rid of the list.remove because it messed up the correct answer segue even more)
- If the wrong answer is pressed, I want it to trigger a segue to another screen with the correct corresponding information

I listed the full code because I don't know if it also has to do with my order or functions.

```
class RoundThree: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var FuelLevel: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var QuestionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Car: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var SmallTown: UIImageView!

    //Outlet for Buttons

    @IBOutlet weak var OptionA: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var OptionB: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var OptionC: UIButton!



    let allQuestions2 = QuestionBank2()
    var questionNumber: Int = 0
    var oldQNumber: Int = 0
    var score: Int = 0
    var selectedAnswer: Int = 0
    var fuelleackage: CGFloat = 0
    var wronganswer: Int = 0
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var questionsasked = [Int]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        newNumber()
        startQuiz()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        }

    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
        if sender.tag == selectedAnswer {
            Car.frame.origin.x  += 40
            score += 1
            fuelleackage += 0.0
            NewYorkCity()

        }  else if sender.tag != selectedAnswer {
            fuelleackage += 40.0
            wronganswer += 1
            EducateYourself()
            NewYorkCity()


        }
        updateUI()

    }

    func updateQuestion(){
            QuestionLabel.text = allQuestions2.list[oldQNumber].question
            OptionA.setTitle(allQuestions2.list[oldQNumber].optionA, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            OptionB.setTitle(allQuestions2.list[oldQNumber].optionB, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            OptionC.setTitle(allQuestions2.list[oldQNumber].optionC, for: UIControl.State.normal)
            selectedAnswer = allQuestions2.list[oldQNumber].CorrectAns
        }




    func updateUI(){
        FuelLevel.frame.size.width = screenSize.width * (1.0-0.15 * CGFloat(wronganswer))
        oldQNumber = questionNumber
        newNumber()
        updateQuestion()
        questionsasked.append(questionNumber)
        }
        //Carol.frame.origin.x  += 30



    func startQuiz (){
        score = 0
        updateQuestion()
        updateUI()
    }


    func NewYorkCity(){
        if (Car.frame.origin.x + (Car.frame.width / 2))  > (SmallTown.frame.origin.x + SmallTown.frame.width) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "FinishWindow", sender: self)
        }
        else if (screenSize.width * (1.0-0.15 * CGFloat(wronganswer)) <= 0)
        { performSegue(withIdentifier: "saaaad", sender: self)
        }
    }

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            if (segue.identifier == "PopUp2") {
                let vc1 = segue.destination as! CorrectInfoPopUp2
                vc1.InformationRoundNumber = oldQNumber
            }
        }
    func EducateYourself(){
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "PopUp2", sender: self)
    }

    func newNumber() {
        for _ in 0..<allQuestions2.list.count {
            var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions2.list.count)))
            while questionsasked.contains(rand) {
                rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions2.list.count)))
            }
            questionNumber = rand
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `newNumber` method you're assigning `questionNumber`, but in prepare for segue you're assigning `oldQNumber` as `vc1`'s variable. Because you don't change `oldQNumber` after you call `newNumber`, I suppose you want to pass `questionNumber`

```
vc1.InformationRoundNumber = questionNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

The same answer as [Robert Dresler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10253094/robert-dresler) written.

And couple of add-ons:

1. Better to use constant for segue identifiers instead of concrete strings:

Example:

```
struct SegueIdentifiers {      
    static let popUp = "PopUp"
    static let finishWindow = "FinishWindow"   
}
```

2. This cast not really safe:

   ```
   if (segue.identifier == "PopUp2") {
       let vc1 = segue.destination as! CorrectInfoPopUp2
       vc1.InformationRoundNumber = oldQNumber
   }
   ```

so a little bit better to write something like this:

```
    if segue.identifier == SegueIdentifiers.popUp, let vc = segue.destination as? CorrectInfoPopUp2 {
        vc.InformationRoundNumber = questionNumber
    }
```

3. If you use swift 4.2 you can use `Int.random(0..<allQuestions2.list.count)` instead of `Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(allQuestions2.list.count)))`

P.S. if you are interesting how to write more readable code, you can check [Raywenderlich's Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide) for example.